# Store custom objects in UILocalNotification's userInfo without encoding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, property-list

I have a custom class called `Person` that I want to store in `UILocalNotification`'s `userInfo` (`NSDictionary`).

Is there any way to save it without converting it to NSData `object` using `-encodeWithCoder:`?

Comment: The object must be put into a serializable format.  NSData is probably the right choice.  Are you having trouble converting to NSData?  Consider solving that problem instead of avoiding it.  Post the issue here if thats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple workaround is to give every person a unique id and store the id in userInfo.
Save an instance of person and fetch it with the id whenever you need to get the userInfo

Answer (score 1):

The userInfo dictionary has some limitations exposed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH44).

So I think, you need to serialize the `Person` object to be able to store it in that location.

Comment: The person is inside an `NSArray` if that's matters

Comment: The storage of your object doesn't matter here, since the cocoa framework will need to explore all the tree of the stored object in the Dictionary.